# Error message: Only user and group IDs may be used in inline mentions

Tags: error-messages, connect-api, inline

I've written a program where I used the ConnectApi class and especially the postFeedElement function. First I've implemented all in a Dev. Org (Spring '15) where I tested it, the tests ran all well. But when I like to push it into our Sandbox (Summer '15) the above error message appears. 
Have anyone experience with this error or with the method I used? I've considered that this may caused by the new release, but I can't find anything about it. 
Thanks a lot for any feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message will appear if:

- You attempt to post an @mention and supply an ID that's not a user or group (see the [ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input_mentionMsgSeg.htm) class).
- The text that you're posting contains a string of the form {@xxx...} or {!xxx...} where xxx... is 15 or 18 characters long and is not a user or group ID.

Do either of these scenarios apply to you?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you alouie, your first option is right. I'm using the ConnectApi along with Salesforce Cases. Each time a Case has been created or closed, a post with an @mention section should appear. The error occurred because in some cases no Case Owner (Account or Contact) is entered. I could solve the problem now. Thank you for your reply, it was very helpful to me. I'm appreciating this very much.